# Angular 2/Ionic 2: Posting data to database

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

Am working on a small ionic-2 projects. I've got stuck at this point.
My question lies in the component section.
Can someone please help me to figure out how to go about it:

```
**<!--TEMPLATE-->**


<select #selected>
<option value="">Choose your details here..</option>

<option *ngFor="let employee of employees; let i = employee" 
[value]="employee.employee_id">

  {{employee.employee_id}}: {{employee.first_name}} 
{{employee.last_name}}

</option>

</select><br><br>

<form>

  <button ion-button (click)="onCheckIn(selected.value)"><ion-icon 
name="person"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;Check-In</button>
  <button ion-button (click) ="onCheckOut(selected.value)"><ion-icon 
name="person"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;Check-Out</button>

</form>
```

---

```
    **// ALSO HAVE A MODEL CLASS**

  export class TimingModel {
  constructor(public employee_id:string,
  public check_in:Date,
  public check_out:Date,
  public check_date:Date,
  public active:boolean)
   {    }
 }
```

---

and,

```
    **//COMPONENT**


onCheckIn(emp_id){

if(emp_id!==""){
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
title: 'Confirm checkout',
message: emp_id+', Do you want to checkout?',
buttons: [
   {
   text: 'Cancel',
   role: 'cancel',
   handler: () => {
  console.log('Cancel checkout: ',emp_id);
  return 
    }
  },
 {
text: 'Yes',
handler: () => {

 // I want to put here some logic here that will make use the model class 
 // to push data into the database as shown in the table.

     }
    }
  ]
 });
 alert.present();
  } else
  {
 this.presentToast();
  } 
}
```

The table to be updated:
[image: The table to be updated]